# Why is my JSON object undefined?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON data structure but what I think should be data is returning undefined.

Here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
....
var messages = data.messages;

$.each(messages, function(i, val) {

    var user = messages[i];

    //console.log(user);
    console.log(user['msg']);

});
```

The PHP data structure look like this:

```
...
$message_info = array();

$message_info[$row['username']]['prvt'] = 1;
$message_info[$row['username']]['msg'] = stripslashes($row['message']);
$message_info[$row['username']]['ts'] = $row['timestamp'];

...

$message_list[] = $message_info;

...

$res->messages = $message_list;
echo json_encode($res);
```

If I dump user to the console the output look like this:Object

```
{john: Object}
  john: Object
  msg: "test msg"
  prvt: 0
  ts: "2012-12-10 09:16:13"
```

This is what data looks like in the console:

```
Object {success: true, lastid: "60", messages: Array[15]}
lastid: "60"
messages: Array[15]
  0: Object
    john: Object
      msg: "test msg"
      prvt: 0
      ts: "2012-12-10 09:16:13"
  1: Object
    john2: Object
      msg: "test msg2"
      prvt: 1
      ts: "2012-12-10 09:18:13"
 ...
```

Any idea why I can't access and retrieve the contents of msg?

Comment: try with `echo json_encode($message_list,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: Are you sure it's not `user.john.msg` ?

Comment: And if the above doesn't work a `console.log(data)` right after you get the `data` variable might help. Note also that you don't need `user = messages[i]` because the `val` parameter will already be set to `messages[i]`.

Comment: Are you getting this JSON using AJAX? Are you trying to access the data before the AJAX callback is complete?

Comment: @nnnnnn Just added output from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your PHP to avoid nesting `msg` inside of `$row['username']`:

```
$message_info = array();
$message_info['username'] = $row['username']; // find this in JS with user['username']
$message_info['prvt'] = 1;
$message_info['msg'] = stripslashes($row['message']);
$message_info['ts'] = $row['timestamp'];
```

With that change, your JavaScript should work as-is.

Comment: That worked but I still don't understand why I couldn't reference the username as the key...

Comment: Because the username is different each time, making it impossible for you to write code to access the data underneath it. If you want to user a username to locate data, loop through the array and test if `user['username']` equals a given string.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was making more difficult then it had to be.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

your user objects contains an object that is referenced by the key "john", "john2" etc.

```
user.john.msg or user.john2.msg
```

should work.

Therefore to build a more generic json structure in php, i would do the following:

```
...
$message_info['user']['name'] = $row['username'];
$message_info['user']['prvt'] = 1;
...
```

Comment: The username could be anything so I can make a static call like that